# Поиск дубликатов в датафреймах большого объёма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Коллеги, добрый день!
Появилась следующая задача: имеется датафрейм большого объёма, который включает в себя ФИО клиента и программу, по которой он пришел.
Мне необходимо сравнить df_1 и df_2, и, тем самым, выявить тех, кто был до НГ, и тех, кто пришел повторно после НГ.
Пытался с помощью `#s1 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='inner', on=['Отбор:'])` , но collab просто выдает ошибку о превышении объёма ОЗУ.

Ниже представлен пример фрейма данных.

```
Indx        Отбор:
201 Павловский Александр Танцыс
202 Штраф за задержку в клубе
203 Посещение 2 часа
204 Посещение 2 часа (Выходные дни)
205 Посещение 3 часа (Выходные дни)
206 Татинцян Оганес Валерьевич
207 Штраф за задержку в клубе
208 Посещение 2 часа
209 Посещение 1 час
210 Посещение 1 час (Выходные дни)
211 Посещение 2 часа (Выходные дни)
212 Шмелев Владислав
213 Штраф за задержку в клубе
214 Посещение 2 часа (Выходные дни)
215 Посещение 3 часа (Выходные дни)
216 Агафонов Алексей Владимирович
217 Штраф за задержку в клубе
218 Посещение 1 час
219 Посещение 1 час (Выходные дни)
220 Посещение 2 часа
221 Афанасьев Николай Максимович
222 Штраф за задержку в клубе
223 Посещение 1 час
224 Посещение 1 час (Выходные дни)
225 Иванова Мария Александровна
226 Штраф за задержку в клубе
227 Посещение 1 час
228 Посещение 1 час (Выходные дни)
229 Посещение 2 часа
```

В общем и целом мне необходимо найти совпадения ФИО в двух фреймах данных.
Датафреймы ничем не отличаются, только периодом времени.

Comment: Если объем данных настолько большой, что не лезет в память, надо разбивать на срезы и сравнивать по кускам. Это в том случае если мы действительно уверены, что дело в превышении памяти. Можно также оставить в покое пандас, превратить две колонки в множества, а затем их пересечь, это на крайний случай. В любом случае, надо больше понимать о данных. Пример, который Вы привели не соответствует Вашему коду, хотя бы потому, что в примере нет колонки "Отбор:"

Comment: СУБД не пробовали?

Comment: Так как нам неизвестно какой объем занимают данные и каким объемом ОЗУ Вы располагаете, то можно что-то советовать только учитывая, что Вы будете проводить эксперименты - влезет или не влезет в память. Я бы начал с того, что очистил бы колонку от служебной информации, иначе когда Вы делаете мерж, Вы тащите с собой не только ФИО, но и вот это вот все. Как очищать - можно пандасом, можно, повторю, превратив все в объекты базового питона.

Comment: `print(set(df_1['Отбор:']) & set(df_2['Отбор:']))`.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, да, я действительно предоставил мало информации по поводу самих данных и ТХ моего ПК))
В следующий раз буду более тщательнее учитывать все факторы. Просто первый раз столкнулся с подобной проблемой.
Насчет деления фрейма на кусочки, думал насчет этого, но хотелось найти метод, который может обработать весь фрейм сразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что проблема в следующем. У Вас в датафрейме, точнее в одной колонке, которую Вы пытаетесь мержить, содержаться одинаковые значения, в большом количестве (служебные строки), которые, судя по всему, содержаться и в первом и во втором датафрейме. В этом случае логика поведения `pd.merge` такова, что она добавляет эти повторяющиеся значения в результирующий датафрейм в количестве m*n, где m и n - количество повторений одного и того же значения в первом и втором датафрейме. В результате этого Ваш результирующий датафрейм *разнесет* до неимоверных размеров и он не влезет ни в какую память.

Поэтому, Вот шаги, которые можно предпринять, чтобы избавится от проблемы:

**1.** Очистить оба датафрейма от служебных строк:

```
df_only_names = df[~df['Отбор:'].str.contains('Штраф|Посещение', regex=True)]
```

Тут надо следить, чтобы нам не попался какой-нибудь *Антон Петрович Штраф(-кин|-ков)*

**2.1** После этого применить `merge` так как Вы его и применяли.

или

**2.2** Сделать из обеих колонок ['Отбор:'] множества и получить их пересечение:

```
names = set(df_1['Отбор:']) & set(df_2['Отбор:'])
```

**3.** Если же Ваш датасет настолько огромен, что очистка датафрейма все равно не поможет (а это будет существенная экономия памяти) и Вы все равно будете получать переполнение, то тогда останется разбивать все данные на срезы (в простом случае - только один из датафреймов, в сложном - оба) и сравнивать кусками в цикле(-ах).

Но все эти советы актуальны в том случае, если Вам нужен просто список ФИО, а не ФИО + служебная информация.

Comment: Потом можно будет используя ФИО через `isin` отобрать нужные строки целиком за датафреймов.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, но что-то мне подсказывает, что автор нам предоставил всю структуру как она у него есть. То есть, по сути - это одномерный набор данных, я из этого исхожу. Усложнит дело, если автору нужны не только ФИО, но и вот эти вот все служебные строки.

Comment: А, ну это да. Похоже у него не нормализованная структура датафреймов и с ней еще работать. Это да.

Comment: @CrazyElf я обновил ответ и добавил новый вопрос по поведению pandas.merge. Если Вам будет интересно - буду благодарен за любые разъяснения.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за уделенное время для моего вопроса.
Насчет merge я и правда получил 24317966 rows в датафрейме.
Также хочу поблагодарить за метод contains (очистки фрейма от ненужных значений), буду исследовать его подробнее.
Да, мне нужны только ФИО, как и было указано в вопросе. Ваш код отлично сработал, только в методе "contains" пришлось добавить параметр na=False, т.к были значения NaN.
Ещё раз спасибо Вам большое за интерес к вопросу и отличный ответ на него.

Answer (score 1):

1. Работайте только с интересующим вас столбцом данных, вы наверняка мержите датафреймы, где много других столбцов, при этом сами эти столбцы вам не нужны на данном этапе. После получения нужного списка ФИО вы по нему сможете отобрать нужные строки из датафреймов.
2. У вас там в столбце не только ФИО, но и какие-то служебные записи. Попробуйте отфильтровать лишние записи по ключевым словам, оставить таким образом только ФИО.
3. Возьмите из столбца список уникальных значений через `.unique()`. Дальше, как вам уже посоветовали в комментариях, можете сделать из этого списка множество и в зависимости от ваших задач пересекать такие множества, складывать, вычитать...

Всё это позволит очень сильно сэкономить используемую память, если делать всё в правильном порядке.

Более конкретно с кодом вам или я или кто-то другой может ответить, если вы предоставите **воспроизводимый пример данных**, т.е. либо файлы с данными, либо код, который можно запустить и получить датафреймы, похожие на ваши по структуре.

Comment: Да, вы правы.
1. Я пытался мержить огромный датафрейм, который имеет 17 столбцов и очень много строк, поэтому памяти не хватало, далее я сам понял эту ошибку, но спасибо Вам, что подметили.

Comment: @Follin Ну, большие датафреймы для опыта полезно покрутить, это приучает думать, что вообще происходит, и не делать таких операций, которые оперируют не нужными вам данными )

Comment: согласен, мне пришла в голову мысль, что некоторые столбцы мне не нужны, только спустя минут 20 :D