# pandas.merge размножает одинаковые значения при слиянии с параметром how="inner"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Коллеги, разбирая [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561691/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B0/1561697?noredirect=1#comment2812693_1561697) столкнулся с поведением `pandas.merge`, логика которого мне совершенно недоступна. Буду благодарен коллегам за объяснение. Даже ссылки на какую-то документация будет вполне достаточно.

**Дано.**

Есть два датафрейма, состоящие из одной колонки и мы пытаемся их смержить по этой колонке.

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'col':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}
dic_1 = {'col':['9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic_1)
df_total = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='col', how='inner')
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
print(df_total)
```

и все в порядке и логично, если значения **хотя бы в одном из датафреймов не повторяются**

```
  col
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
```

**Но вот вопрос.**

Если одно и тоже значение повторяется в обоих датафреймах, то результирующий датафрейм будет включать это значение m*n раз, где m и n - количество повторений значения в первом и втором датафрейме соответственно:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'col':['1','2','3','3','3','6','7','8','9']}
dic_1 = {'col':['9','8','7','6','5','3','3','2','1']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic_1)
df_total = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='col', how='inner')
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
print(df_total)
```

Вот результат:

```
   col
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    6
9    7
10   8
11   9
```

Все результаты получены эмпирическим путем и о логике я могу только строить предположения.

Буду благодарен за объяснения.

Comment: Вроде выглядит логично...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот случай является слиянием "многие ко многим" (many_to_many) - когда и слева и справа ключи для слияния с дубликатами - и актуален как для "inner", так и для "outer", "left" и "right".
Какие есть варианты слияния при таком раскладе?

1. Взять множество ключей слева и сопоставить каждый из них с одним ключом справа. Возникает неопределенность - какой именно ключ справа взять? Первый, последний, случайный или связывать по порядку (первый с первым, второй со вторым; ... а если дубликатов ключей слева 3, а справа 7? и строки в неопределённом порядке). Такой подход не годится, поскольку недетерминирован.
2. Взять множество ключей слева и сопоставить каждый из них с каждым ключом справа. Здесь неопределенность пропадает - будут проверены и связаны все ключи.

Поэтому оно так и работает, это просто нужно учитывать.
А если вам критично, чтобы не было такого "размножения", можно использовать аргумент [`validate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), в котором задать допустимый вариант слияния, например "many_to_one" - тогда при варианте "many_to_many" возникнет исключение. Ну или проверять фреймы до слияния на предмет уникальности ключей.

[Доп. инфо. (англ)](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.07-merge-and-join.html#Many-to-many-joins)

Comment: Я понял, почему я так затупил. В рассматриваемом вопросе одна колонка и когда она мержится, то отсутствие дополнительных колонок с информацией делает логику непрозрачной. Но стоит, хотя бы мыслено добавить другие поля - и логика визуализируется. Благодарю, ответ исчерпывающий.

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить столбик идентификаторов и разглядеть наглядно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
dic = {'col':['a','a','b','b'],'zn':[1,2,3,4]}
dic_1 = {'col':['a','a','a','b'],'zn':[10,20,30,40]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic_1)
df_total = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='col', how='inner')
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
print(df_total)
```

Comment: Да, меня как раз с толку сбило отсутствие других колонок в изначальном вопросе. Когда есть другие колонки понять, конечно проще. Спасибо, плюсанул.

Answer (score 2):

inner не имеет отношения к тому, как обходиться с дубликатами, это про то, что "сопоставить каждый ключевой элемент слева с каждым ключевым элементом справа и вывести строки, где эти элементы совпадают". Если ключи повторяются, то просто каждый из повторяющихся ключей будет участвовать в сопоставлении, отсюда и получается "размножение". Хотите, чтобы не было дубликатов - разбирайтесь с ними сами либо до merge, либо после.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, совместными усилиями мне разъяснили суть! Плюсанул.